# Exporting data from single excel spreadsheet into multiple word templates

Tags: vba, excel, templates, ms-word

Apologies if the answer is out there, I cannot see anything specific to what I am asking and really just need to know whether it is possible and the best method for doing so before going any further.

I have a spread sheet with a number of fields containing text. These each need to be transferred over to different word templates (10 templates total), the sheet also contains columns which give directions as to where each item goes in each template. (some will go to more than one template)

The ultimate goal would be to automate the process of producing the templates from the spread sheet.

So far my initial ideas are:

> Using the mail merge feature (I have never done so, so will have to look into this)
>
> Using VBA script

Are either of these viable for what I want to do? (I think I can easily create a macro to arrange the data in excel, my real issue is getting into the correct word templates automatically)

If they are both viable, which would be easier?

Sorry if this is not very clear, I just want to get an informed impression before taking this forward to be honest.

Thanks

Comment: I would think VBA in Excel would be able to accomplish this. But some things are not clear. Do you want the Word docs you create to have an updated version of the Excel file or a static version? Example you can link the Excel file such that if changes are made to the Excel file, then the changes are updated to the word documents automatically. Doing this can possibly create other issues, however… if you went with this (manual) approach, you would need only to do this once and not have to do it again… i.e. manually create the Excel links in the Word templates.

Comment: The issues/problems that could arise are always re-linking the Word/Excel files when open/closed, there could be possible network issues maintaining this “link” to the Excel file. Depending on what you want your finished product to be, VBA should work, if you are familiar with VBA, I would start there. C# is my choice but anything dealing with Word is usually a challenge in itself. Good Luck.

Comment: Thanks for the info. A new excel file is created on a weekly basis. The content is transferred to appropriate word templates and saved as PDF. I will look into using VBA.

Answer (score 0):

Mail Merge should certainly do it for you.  If you want to use DocVariables, you can do that as well.  Here is a sample script for you to try out.

```
Sub PushToWord()

Dim objWord As New Word.Application
Dim doc As Word.Document
Dim bkmk As Word.Bookmark
sWdFileName = Application.GetOpenFilename(, , , , False)
Set doc = objWord.Documents.Open(sWdFileName)

objWord.activedocument.variables("FirstName").Value = Range("FirstName").Value
objWord.activedocument.variables("LastName").Value = Range("LastName").Value

ActiveDocument.Fields.Update

objWord.Visible = True

End Sub
```

Comment: Amazing thank you! I am still working on this, needless to say it is going slowly, but this is very much appreaciated